# The best way to handle the concurrent saving of 2 identical entities via hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, redis, spring-data-jpa, concurrency

Problem:
Entity is saving from 2 places concurrently. - the result is duplication exception by unique key - 'external_id'.

1. Backend service.

- send a POST request to the external service
- saves entity to DB

2. External webhook.

- comes from an external service and we need to save the same entity to our DB.

[image]

We don't know if it is saved on the BE side already (transaction not committed ye, or if it just comes from webhook due to user manual action.

Our current solution: distributed lock.
We are using the Redisson distributed lock to handle such cases. This makes the code very complicated. But maybe you are faced with such issues and know a better solution.